# How to print the complete content of an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a code snippet as below

```
# Get top 10 CPU hogging process
    my $prumObj = OvPrum->new($OVOSystem, $Session);
    my $numprocs = 10;
    my $ProcString= "";
    my $ProcessList = $prumObj->getTopCPUHoggingProcess($numprocs); 
    if ( $ProcessList and scalar(@$ProcessList) )
    {
        $ProcString = "Top ".$numprocs." CPU hogging processes are listed below :\n";
        $ProcString .= "\nCPU   PID Process\n\n";
        foreach ( @$ProcessList)
        {
            $ProcString .= $$_{pctcpu}."    ".$$_{pid}."    ".$$_{args}."\n";
        }
    }
```

The output of the above snippet is

```
Top 10 CPU hogging processes are listed below :
% CPU   PID    Process

100    6092     CPUSTRES
6      4252     opcmona
```

However I would want to get all the fields (instead of %CPU, PID and Process). How can I get all the fields assigned to the variable ProcString?

Could you please help me in this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Show an example of the data structure you're working with and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Hi Melpomene, The tool uses this code internally. I dont have any means to test it apart from looking at output directly. This code gives the top 10 processes and their corresponding cpu%,process id and arguments(description). I would like to print all the fields to be printed. I dont know how to print all the fields.could you please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the tool" What tool?

Comment: Its a microfocus software tool. It prints the top processes and the CPU utilization as shown below.This may affect overall performance of the system. Top 10 CPU hogging processes are listed below :

% CPU PID  Host Process

100 6092     CPUSTRES
6 4252     opcmona

Comment: What do you mean, "as shown below"? You haven't posted any sample output. You also haven't explained what other fields there are or what your desired output looks like.

Comment: i edited the previous post for your reference

Comment: Add all relevant information to your question. Putting it in a comment isn't good because 1) not all people read comments and 2) you can't use nice formatting in comments.

Comment: I am unaware of the syntax.. If                                                
    $ProcString .= $$_{pctcpu}." ".$$_{pid}." ".$$_{args}."\n";                      can print                                                                                                             % CPU PID  Host Process

100 6092     CPUSTRES                                                                            how can i modify the code such that it prints all the fields ?

Comment: @GirishJoshi: `$$_{pctcpu}` is just an overcomplicated way to write `$_->{pctcpu}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the code you have shown was written by someone who doesn't know as much Perl as they think they know. Everywhere that they have a construct like `$$_{pctcpu}`, a real Perl programmer would have written `$_->{pctcpu}`. They also didn't know that variables are interpolated in a double-quoted Perl string. So the last line of code would actually have been written as:

```
$ProcString .= "$_->{pctcpu}   $_->{pid}    $_->{args}\n";
```

Secondly, you need to realise that no-one here knows what the `OvPrum` module is or how it works. So all of this is guesswork.

Having said that. It seems pretty clear that your `getTopCPUHoggingProcess()` method is returning an array reference and that every element of the referenced array is a hash reference.

So I think your question is actually, "given an array of hash references, how can I print all of the values from the array, not just the ones the current code explicitly asks for". And I think the code below answers that. Notice that I've faked the definition of the `$ProcessList` variable. My version certainly won't be accurate, but it should be close enough to enable you to work out what is going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ProcessList = [{
  pctcpu => 3,
  pid    => 1000,
  args   => 'something',
  extra  => 'Important data',
}, {
  pctcpu => 2,
  pid    => 2000,
  args   => 'something else',
  extra  => 'Vital data',
}];

my $ProcString = '';

# Get all of the keys of the first hash in the array
my @keys = keys %{ $ProcessList->[0] };

print "@keys\n";

foreach (@$ProcessList) {
  $ProcString .= join(' ', @{$_}{ @keys }) . "\n";
}

print "$ProcString\n";
```

Comment: Hi Dave. This code did work. It prints all the fields. Though my next question is beyond the scope, i would like to ask it.  I was expecting it to print the username of the processes, however it didnt. I suspect the getTopCPUHoggingProcess() . Aint it?

Comment: @GirishJoshi: You would need to read the documentation of the module. But I wouldn't be surprised if it gives you the userid (perhaps a `uid` column?) rather than username.